# How to control visibility in Android, is this an error?

Tags: android, adapter

When the `FeedGroupID != 10`, I set `holder.group_check.setVisibility(View.GONE)`, but it's still displayed.

```xml
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/group_check"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text=" > "
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_uploader_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="mumbiker.nikkhil"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Adapter code:

```java
if (newFeedModel.getFeedGroupID() != "10") {
    holder.group_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.tv_uploader_group.setText(newFeedModel.getFeedGroupName());
} else {
    holder.group_check.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.tv_uploader_group.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

and I got this error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
```

why it's

```
error ->　holder.group_check.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: group_check is null.

Comment: please share your adapter code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Does your imported file is same as xml file? Like `import ...my_layout.view` and `my_layout.xml`.
2. Does your layout Id `R.layout.my_layout` in `onCreateViewHolder` is same as `my_layout.xml`?

**Note:** `my_layout` just for example.

Answer (score 0):

If your **views in holder are initialised** and everything is working fine without crashing, then the problem lies in the if statement.

If the **newFeedModel.getFeedGroupID()**  is returning string, then compare it using the **equals()** method as shown below :

```
if(newFeedModel.getFeedGroupID().equals("10")) { 
    //perform operations
} else {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using in Fragment you have to call in this method [ override fun (onViewCreated) ]